CORS error showing even when the backend access control allow origin is set for frontend url after deployment on vercel
I have deployed my mern app's frontend and backend on vercel on 2 different url's.
For backend i have set :
app.use(cors({credentials : true , origin : 'https://music-app-client-five.vercel.app'}));

my frontend url :

https://music-app-client-five.vercel.app

One request to backend from frontend :
useEffect(() => {
      const getSongs = async ()=>{
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${PROXY_URL}/api/song/list` , {
                credentials : 'include',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                }
            })
            const data = await response.json();
            if (data?.error) {
                return;
            }
            // console.log(data);
            if (response.ok) {
             setSongList(data.message);  
             setTrack(data.message[0]) ;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      }
      getSongs();
    }, [])

My cookie config :
export const generateTokenAndSetCookie = (userId , res)=>{
    const token = jwt.sign({userId} , process.env.JWT_SECRET , {
        expiresIn : '15d', 
    } )
    res.cookie('jwt', token , {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'None'
    })

The error :

Access to fetch at
'https://music-app-server-bice.vercel.app/api/song/list' from origin
'https://music-app-client-five.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS
policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
'https://music-app-client-five.vercel.app/' that is not equal to the
supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value,
or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to
'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

why it is happening like this?

'Maybe' first use dynamic origin check in the server instead of hardcoding the origin in your cors configuration. Second, I think there is no need for "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true in the front-end since you are using ' credentials: 'include','

Everything works fine if i do it for http://localhost:3000 for frontend. Why is it?

what the production environment that you use for hosting your app ?

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials does not belong in a request, since it's a response header; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
